# Conversion of date from string to datetime then inserting it into with c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime

Question: why do I get the day before when I convert string to datetime using C#?

When I try to convert a date from string to datetime then inserting it into a Mongodb database, I get the day before!

For example

Datetime "12/01/2014"

I get in the database "2014-11-30T23:00:00.000Z"

This is my code

```
 devises2.date_observation_d = DateTime.ParseExact(item[0], "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @marc_s How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: How do you insert your `devises2.date_observation_d` to the database exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must explicitly specify UTC time to avoid time zone conversion issues:

```
devices.some_date = (new DateTime(2014, 12 , 1)).ToUniversalTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the "MM/dd/yyyy" format, then "12/01/2014" is December 01 2014.

You probably have November 30th because you have 1 hour of timezone conversion.

Try to parse with this code:

```
devises2.date_observation_d = DateTime.ParseExact(
    item[0], 
    "dd/MM/yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
);
```

Comment: I get the same problem !!

Comment: Can you write the value of item[0]?